# Tire gem: Use only to generate query instead of executing the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tire

I am using tire gem to query elasticsearch in my database. Now, I have a model `ContentElastic` which connects to index `posts` and mapping `post`. I am using elasticsearch as a single database and not as a search engine over another database. So, the model `ContentElastic` goes like this:

```
class ContentElastic
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  index_name 'posts'
  document_type 'post'

  # fields
  property :id
  property :type, :type => "string"
  property :username 
  property :name 
  property :datasource 
  property :content 
  property :language_id, :type => "long" 
  property :geotag 
  property :geo_enabled, :type => "boolean"
  property :language_confidence, :type => "long"
  property :tweet_id
  ...

end
```

Now, I have written a query like this, to get 10,000 records from the elasticsearch database:

```
ContentElastic.search do
  fields wanted_fields if wanted_fields.present?

  query do
    filtered do
      query { string search_query } if search_query.present?
      #### Filters 
      range_filters.to_a.each do |rf|
        filter :range, rf if rf.present?
      end

      not_filters.to_a.each do |nf|
        filter :not, nf if nf.present?
      end

      or_filters.to_a.each do |of|
        filter :or, of if of.present?
      end

      and_filters.to_a.each do |af|
        filter :and, af if af.present?
      end

      filter :script, {:script => script} if script.present?

      terms_filters.to_a.each do |tf|
        filter :terms, tf if tf.present?
      end
    end
  end

  size 10000
end
```

The query is working fine, and we are getting the results. The problem, is that, for 10,000 records, the conversion to ruby objects takes time. Is there a way to get the elasticsearch query directly from the tire declaration and call it separately via RestClient.

Is there a way to get the elasticsearch query without executing the query in Tire. I tried `to_curl` method in Tire immediately after the tire search block, but it seems the query is already executed and it says `Undefined method 'to_curl' for <#Tire::Collection>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for this. Instead of calling `ContentElastic.search` directly, I was able to call `Tire.search` like this:

```
tire_block = Proc.new do
  fields wanted_fields if wanted_fields.present?

  query do
    filtered do
      query { string search_query } if search_query.present?
      #### Filters 
      range_filters.to_a.each do |rf|
        filter :range, rf if rf.present?
      end

      not_filters.to_a.each do |nf|
        filter :not, nf if nf.present?
      end

      or_filters.to_a.each do |of|
        filter :or, of if of.present?
      end

      and_filters.to_a.each do |af|
        filter :and, af if af.present?
      end

      filter :script, {:script => script} if script.present?

      terms_filters.to_a.each do |tf|
        filter :terms, tf if tf.present?
      end
    end
  end

  size 10000
end

t = Tire.search(ContentElastic.index.name, :type => ContentElastic.document_type, :size => limit, :from => from, &tire_block)
```

This tire call was not executing the query, but was giving the tire search object. Then, I was able to execute the elastic query corresponding using RestClient like this:

```
post_url = t.url + (t.params.empty? ? '?' : t.params.to_s)
response = RestClient.post(post_url, t.to_json.gsub("'",'\u0027'))
```

The response will be the json string from elasticsearch and I was able to use this json_string by parsing using `JSON.parse` and taking the appropriate tags.